# Block QoS packets from WiFi Router

Tags: networking, firewall, qos

I am currently trying to do some WiFi sensing using Channel State Information (CSI).

Unfortunately, every WiFi Router I have sends random QoS-packets to the WiFi clients and they are interrupting my CSI capturing. I also didn't find a way to turn QoS off in the router, so my next best option is to try to block them in Linux.

For example, the CSI-capturing-program (PicoScenes) prints out the QoS packets like this:

`MACHeader[type=[DF]QoS Data, dest=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx, src=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx, ...`

Is there a way to block packets with Type `Data` and Subtype `QoS Data` as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/802.11_Frame_Types#Types_and_SubTypes)?

Comment: not quite sure why QoS packets are problematic for your CSI sensing?